# LINQ intersect() method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following tables:

[image]

Each CoffeeLover has several FavouriteCoffeeRecords associated with him. I want to get list of CoffeeNames for a given CoffeeLoverID using LINQ query.

I guess I need to use `Intersect()` method.
I have tried like this:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{   
    var favCofRecords = db.FavouriteCoffeesRecords.Where(q => q.CoffeeLover.CoffeeLoverID == 1);
    var favCoffees = db.Coffees.Select(q => q.CoffeeID).Intersect(favCofRecords.Select(q2 => q2.CoffeeID));
}
```

But failed to get the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in a too complicated way. You want the coffee names for which there is a relationship with a given `CoffeeLoverID`:

```
var results = 
 from c in db.Coffees
 where c.FavouriteCoffeesRecords.Any(rec => rec.CoffeeLoverID == someID)
 select c.Name;
```

This is literally the query that I described in prose.

When you want to query columns from a certain table, start with that table in the `from` clause and filter it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a `join`

```
from f in db.FavouriteCoffeesRecords
join c in db.Coffees on f.CoffeeID equals c.CoffeeID
where f.CoffeeLover.CoffeeLoverID == 1
select c.CoffeeName
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this solution. May I ask you to rewrite it using lambda ?